# Insert values in temp table form same table and different variables

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I have this code, that works, but I want to insert in the temp table the same values (DateTime and Value) from another variable (UBB_PreT_Line_LA.If_TotalInFeddWeight) present in the same table ([Runtime].[dbo].[History]). Then, I show the result in SQL Report Builder 3.0 in a table.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @fechaItem DATETIME;
DECLARE @fechaFinTotal DATETIME;
SET @fechaItem = DateAdd(hh,7,@Fecha)
SET @fechaFinTotal =  DateAdd(hh,23,@Fecha)
SET NOCOUNT OFF

DECLARE @tblTotales TABLE
(
VALOR_FECHA DATETIME,
VALOR_VALUE float
)

WHILE @fechaItem < @fechaFinTotal
BEGIN   

DECLARE @fechaFin DATETIME;
SET @fechaFin =  DATEADD(minute, 15, @fechaItem );

INSERT INTO @tblTotales
SELECT 
MAX( [DateTime] ), 
MAX( [Value] )
FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
WHERE 
[DateTime] >= @fechaItem  
AND [DateTime] <= @fechaFin
AND (History.TagName='UBB_PreT_Belt_PF101A.Time_Running')

SET @fechaItem = @fechaFin;

END

SELECT TOP 64 VALOR_FECHA as Fecha,VALOR_VALUE as Valor
FROM @tblTotales
order by Valor ASC
```

What I want, is to join in a single query the result I get in these two tables, with the same query in which only the variable that is queried changes.

The purpose is to create a unique Dataset in Report Builder to display in a single table, the data of the two tables of the image. The 15 minute interval is because I just want to show the variation of the values every 15 minutes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbVU1.png)

I have modified the code (Image_02), and with the Query Designer of the Report Builder I have obtained what is shown in the Image_03. The final goal would be to have the data of the second variable, in two more columns on the right (Fecha_Ton and Valor_Ton). How can I do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbVU1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBqzF.png)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Some **sample data** and **expected results** would help immensely. I'm also not at all sure why you're building up this data *row by agonising row* rather than writing a single query that groups your data on 15 minute intervals.

Comment: I have modified the code (Image_02), and with the Query Designer of the Report Builder I have obtained what is shown in the Image_03. The final goal would be to have the data of the second variable, in two more columns on the right (Fecha_Ton and Valor_Ton). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, I think that this query replaces your code entirely (and adds the second value):

```
declare @sample table (Datetime datetime not null, Value int not null, 
                       TagName varchar(50) not null)
insert into @sample (DateTime, Value, TagName) values
('2018-08-16T10:14:00',6,'UBB_PreT_Belt_PF101A.Time_Running'),
('2018-08-16T10:08:00',8,'UBB_PreT_Belt_PF101A.Time_Running'),
('2018-08-16T10:23:00',7,'UBB_PreT_Belt_PF101A.Time_Running'),
('2018-08-16T10:07:00',7,'UBB_PreT_Line_LA.If_TotalInFeddWeight')

declare @Fecha datetime
set @Fecha = '20180816'

select
    MAX(DateTime),
    MAX(CASE WHEN TagName='UBB_PreT_Line_LA.If_TotalInFeddWeight' THEN Value END) as Fed,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TagName='UBB_PreT_Belt_PF101A.Time_Running' THEN Value END) as Running
from
    @sample
where
    DateTime >= DATEADD(hour,7,@Fecha) and
    DateTime < DATEADD(hour,23,@Fecha) and
    TagName in ('UBB_PreT_Line_LA.If_TotalInFeddWeight',
                'UBB_PreT_Belt_PF101A.Time_Running')
group by DATEADD(minute,((DATEDIFF(minute,0,DateTime)/15)*15),0)
order by MAX(DateTime) asc
```

Results:

```
                        Fed         Running
----------------------- ----------- -----------
2018-08-16 10:14:00.000 7           8
2018-08-16 10:23:00.000 NULL        7
```

(You may want two separate dates following the same pattern using `CASE` as the values)

You shouldn't be building your data up [*row by agonising row*](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/)<sup>1</sup>, you should find as way (such as that above) to express what the *entire* result set should look like as a single query. Let SQL Server itself decide whether it's going to do that by searching through the rows in date order, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup>There may be circumstances where you end up having to do this, but first exhaust any likely set-based options first.